# Spring Boot viewControllerHandlerMapping Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here's a sample gist of my Application.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.com.app.client.controller")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.com.app")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "org.com.app.model")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    /**
     * Spring Web MVC Confugrations
     *
     **/
    @Bean
    public ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(){
        ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
        return  exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return  viewResolver;
    }
```

However when I try to run my mvn spring-boot:run this exception always occurs. what am I missing?

```
12:30:22.670 [org.brightworks.genesis.client.Application.main()] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may
     not be accessed if they are not currently started
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.brightworks.genesis.client.Application.main(Application.java:38) [classes/:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:232) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:533) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
            at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.exists(ServletContextResource.java:102) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addStaticIndexHtmlViewControllers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:275) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addViewControllers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:270) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addViewControllers(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addViewControllers(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.viewControllerHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:346) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76267062.CGLIB$viewControllerHandlerMapping$20(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76267062$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$259225cd.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76267062.viewControllerHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
            ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think the issue could be the version of embedded tomcat that you are using, you appear to have pulled in 8.0.3 version, whereas the one that comes with 1.2.3 of Spring Boot should have been 8.0.20, can you check why you are getting this older version and that should fix up your issue

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution. I was using the incorrect version of servlet. I was on Servlet version 3.0.1, I've overriden the default Servlet version of spring boot hence the error.

Comment: Yes, I encounter the same issue. Change Servlet version to 3.1.0 fix the problem.