# Loading resources in PostConstruct method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm having difficulties loading a resource file from a method annotated with @PostConstruct within a service.

```
@Service
    public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    //@Autowired
    //private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {

        Resource res = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath*:myResource.csv");
        //Resource res = applicationContext.getResource("classpath*:myResource.csv");

        ... use loaded resource ...

    }

}
```

I keep receiving the error `IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started`.

Where am I going wrong? Is it something with the order of bean initialization perhaps?

Comment: @PostConstruct is called after bean is fully intialized, so ideally ResourceLoader should have been injected. Maybe, Servlet version issue? Have a look here at answer posted over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29453024/1969874

Answer (score 0):

If you are only loading a single resource then remove the asterisk (*) from your classpath and ensure that the file is located in src/main/resources

My instinct is that this is a classpath issue and something isn't matching.  If you're still having trouble, upload a sample project that illustrates this issue.